# Provisioning code regular expression

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to develop a C code that checks the validity of "Provisioning code" string using regular expressions.
A "provisioning code" format should respect the following law:

***If not an empty string, this argument SHOULD be in the form of a hierarchical descriptor with one or more nodes specified. Each node in the hierarchy is represented as a 4-character sub-string, containing only numerals or upper-case letters. If there is more than one node indicated, each node is separated by a "." (dot). Examples: "TLCO" or "TLCO.GRP2".***

I started development using the code in this link http://web.archive.org/web/20160308115653/http://peope.net/old/regex.html

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "^a[[:alnum:]]", 0);
    if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, "abc", 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
            puts("Match");
    }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
            puts("No match");
    }
    else{
            regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
            exit(1);
    }

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
}
```

this code works fine but my problem is what's the best regular expression that should be input of the function regcomp.

I started to try with a regular expression that matches with string that contains exactly 4 characters uppercases or numerals that means example like TLCO or TLC2 trying with the regular expression "[A-Z0-9]{4}" but I get "No match" as output with matches examples like TLC2.

Is there a suggestion about the right regular expression that should be input of regcomp and matches with "provisioning code"?

Comment: Try `^[A-Z0-9]+([.][A-Z0-9]+)*$` and pass `REG_EXTENDED` to `regcomp` - `reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[A-Z0-9]+([.][A-Z0-9]+)*$", REG_EXTENDED);`

Comment: Why did you try `^a[[:alnum:]]` pattern? Should the codes start with `a` and then contain even lowercase letters? Also, you are testing against `abc` string, so what are the real requirements?

Comment: In basic mode regex you should probably backslash-escape curlies: `[A-Z0-9]\{4\}`. Since it's C you should escape each backslash too, so regex string should be: "^[A-Z0-9]\\{4\\}\\(\\.[A-Z0-9]\\{4\\}\\)*$". If you set extended mode (via flags in regcomp last argument) it will work without all backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion generally works fine but  I think that each node substring should contain exactly 4 characters

Comment: So, `"^[A-Z0-9]{4}([.][A-Z0-9]{4})*$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex that will work alright if you also pass `REG_EXTENDED` flag to the `regcomp` method (for the `$` and `{m,n}` modifier to work correctly):

```
^[A-Z0-9]{4}([.][A-Z0-9]{4})*$
```

C code:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[A-Z0-9]{4}([.][A-Z0-9]{4})*$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9]{4}` - 4 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `([.][A-Z0-9]{4})*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[.]` - a literal `.` char
  - `[A-Z0-9]{4}` - 4 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @user7231 Sorry, I have got a new keyboard today, and have to get accustomed to it :(